# Can someone give me an example of a layered architecture?

Tags: java, layer

I have to do a java application for bank employees hat can add/delete/update accounts and I don't know how to implement a layered architecture. I have the Gui, the database, I know something about the layered architecture but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: this questions is way too generic!!

Comment: Writing a code for you maybe will help you for this task, but not for the future. I suggest you to try to write a minimal thing, and if you'll still have problems, SO is here.

Comment: I'm too lazy at my homework !!!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is so broad, I'll answer very broadly.

*Generally* it is perceived as a distinctive separation in application behaviour and state, each of which is designed to be applied only to its given concern and should not leak into another's.

This usually ends up as:
A presentation layer (web, desktop gui's, consoles, etc), a Service (business rules go here) layer and a data access layer (DAOs, repositories, etc).

Answer (score 0):

question is too generic, but layered architecture is something that can be applied anywhere. So Android is a good example of layered architecture.

see here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/index.html